# Mini-$abc$ conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

Define $\text{rad}_{23}(2^m3^nr)=2^{\text{sign}(m)}3^{\text{sign}(n)}r$, where $m,n\ge0$ and $2,3\nmid r\in\mathbb{N}$.

For a triple $a+b=c$ define the quality $q_{23}(a,b,c)=\frac{\log(c)}{\log(\text{rad}_{23}(abc))}$.

Has anyone attempted to *specifically* prove that only finitely many primitive triples have quality $q_{23}>1+\epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon>0$? Is there reason to hope this may be within reach of well established methods?

Based on [this table](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/index.php?set=2) of $abc$-triples, only 2 mini-$abc$-triples: are known with quality $\ge1.4$:

$37 + 2^{15}  = 3^8 \times 5,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ q_{23}=1.48291$

$5 + 3^{11}  = 2^{10} \times 173,\ \ \ \ \ q_{23}=1.41268$

Comment: We are dealing with triples of the form $p+q2^m=r3^n$ or similar, with $p,q,r$ "small", which in particular gives $q2^m\approx r3^n$. Using Baker's theorem it should be possible to give some nontrivial bounds on the quality.

Comment: what is $\mathrm{sign}(m)$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: sign(0)=0, sign(a)=1 if a>0.

Comment: It's worth noting that the $2^{sign(m)}3^{sign(n)}$ is immaterial, since its log is obviously $o(\log c)$, so you might as well get rid of it.